# Netbeans Java Error: Invalid Character Value for Cast

Tags: java, casting, int

Im having trouble inserting records to my database I guess theres something wrong with my ints and string?

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

            Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\kim\\Desktop\\Thesis Docu\\FPAS\\FPAS.accdb");
            Statement s = dbConn.createStatement();
            ResultSet mResult =s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tblstudentrecord");
            if(mResult.next()){
                String sql = "INSERT INTO tblstudentrecord(studentID,instructorID,courseID,day,date,time,Category1,Category2,a,b,c,d,e,Rating,Comment) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement insert = dbConn.prepareStatement(sql);
                insert.setString(1,jLabel2.getText());
                insert.setString(2,jTxtFaculty.getText());                    
                insert.setString(3,jTxtCourse.getText());
                insert.setString(4,jTxtDay.getText());
                insert.setString(5,jLabel35.getText());
                insert.setString(6,jTxtTime.getText());
                int i = Integer.parseInt(radio);
                int i1 = Integer.parseInt(radio1);
                int i2 = Integer.parseInt(radio2);
                int i4 = Integer.parseInt(radio4);
                int i6 = Integer.parseInt(radio6);
                insert.setInt(7,i);
                insert.setInt(8,i1);
                insert.setInt(9,i2);
                insert.setString(10,radio3);
                insert.setInt(11,i4);
                insert.setString(12,radio5);
                insert.setInt(13,i6);
                insert.setString(14,radio7);
                insert.setString(15,jTextField1.getText());
            FacultyName.removeAllItems();
                         insert.execute();
```

Comment: Please show the compilation error message or exception stack trace you are getting.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with my commas or double quotes in saving an int value? the radio(s) are the values with int data type..

Comment: I don't see any type cast in the code; usually reading up the compilation error messages/stack trace solves a problem. Possibly, you could split your insert statement string into smaller parts and then look at the line the error occurs.

Comment: well i really dont get whats the problem with my insert  statement my error is "invalid character value for cast"

Comment: Why are your "radio" lines not all the same?

Comment: the radios(1-5) are int while the others are string?

Comment: anybody who knows the error im getting?

Comment: @bloomindindin *You* should be the one who knows the error. Update your question to include the compile error message.

Comment: Please please please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) before you write another line of code like this.

Comment: @JacobRaihle You pasted in the wrong link, actually it's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yeah im sorry if im asking this kind of question but I was only given 3 days and im really in hurry to finish my system..sorry if this bothers you..but I know the error is with the int data types...is my commas and double quotes are correct?

Comment: @bloomindindin It depends on what you are expecting the statement to be after concatenation. At least the syntax is correct. As for the datatypes, I don't know.

Comment: yeah..but I what I knew is that when it is string data type in inserting it goes like this + " ' " + jTxtFaculty.getText() +" '," when an int data type?

Comment: Java handles String concatenation with datatypes other than ``String`` - Expect ``"a" + b + "c"``to have the same result as an invocation of ``String.valueOf``: ``"a" + String.valueOf(`` *``b``* ``) + "c"``

Comment: Guys those string functions shows an invalid character cast as ive tried it..errors are the same?

Answer (score -1):

```
PreparedStatement insert = dbConn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tblstudentrecord(studentID,instructorID,courseID,day,date,time,Category1,Category2,a,b,c,d,e,Rating,Comment) VALUES ("
                 + "'" + x +"'," 
                 + "'" + x +"',"
                 + "'" + x +"',"
                 + "'" + x +"',"
                 + "'" + x +"',"
                 + "'" + x +"',"
                 + "'" + radio +"',"
                 + "'" + radio1 +"',"
                 + "'" + radio2 +"',"
                 + "'" + radio3 +"',"
                 + "'" + radio4 +"',"
                 + "'" + radio5 +"',"
                 + "'" + radio6 +"',"
                 + "'" + radio7 +"',"
                 + "'" + jTextField1.getText() +"'"
                 +")");
```

Comment: Nope. That isn't a proper answer. It doesn't explain anything nor is it in any way helpful.

Comment: im getting the same error when I did that earlier..I guess it it is in my insert statement..anyways thank you for the respond :)

Comment: Why the downvote? OPs quoted string wasn't correct. I merely corrected it. If radio, radio1, etc are ints then there isn't anything else required but to just fix his quoted string.

Answer (score -1):

Your quoting is wrong! Also, which type are "radio" variables? If those are int, then you can try using toString() method. Try it like this (toString() is optional, but I left it for you to see how to use it):

```
PreparedStatement insert = dbConn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tblstudentrecord(studentID,instructorID,courseID,day,date,time,Category1,Category2,a,b,c,d,e,Rating,Comment) VALUES ("
         + "'" + jLabel2.getText() +"',"  
         + "'" + jTxtFaculty.getText() +"'," 
         + "'" + jTxtCourse.getText() +"',"
         + "'" + jTxtDay.getText() +"',"
         + "'" + jLabel35.getText() +"',"
         + "'" + jTxtTime.getText() +"',"
         + radio.toString() + ","
         + radio1.toString() + ","
         + radio2.toString() + ","
         + radio3.toString() + ","
         + radio4.toString() +","
         + radio5.toString() + ","
         + radio6.toString() +","
         + radio7.toString() +","
         + "'" + jTextField1.getText() +"'"
         +")");
```

Although, it does sound like radio variables are some controls from some form. If they are, make sure to use proper function which extract values from them.

Comment: java does not support method invocation on primitives. Your "answer" is just a guess and should be a comment instead.

Comment: the error that i am getting now is RADIO: invalid schema >_<

Comment: I forgot to fix quotes so I edited my answer right after I posted it.

Comment: Related to the edit: *Where* is the quoting wrong? I haven't seen any syntactical mistake in the authors code.

Comment: Try without toString(). And please make sure radios are integer. Post me a decleration of radio if needed.

Comment: + "  + radio + ,"+ "  + radio1 + ," + "  + radio2 + ,"+ "  + radio3 + ,". Radio variables are INSIDE string.

Comment: when I copied that.. the error that im getting ws unexpected token: 6 required: ) Omgoshh..I feel like my brains gonna explode..wish  can complete the module by wednesday >_< im really in need ofhelp guys! :'(